# Java Collision Detection

Tags: java, drawing, collision

I am attempting to detect collisions between two shapes using `intersects`, however, the detection is not working.

Printing out the `Circle` objects reveal the x and y positions are set as 0. I suspected that maybe the position getter and setter methods were not working correctly, however, printing out this information reveals non-zero values.

Why is the detection not working?

Thank you.

Edit: The below code is now working. See comments for detail of the issue / solution.

Main Class

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main extends JPanel {

    public static List<Circle> circleList = new ArrayList<>();
    private static Random random = new Random();    

    public Main() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            circleList.add(new Circle(random.nextInt(500), random.nextInt(500)));
        }       
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);   
        for (Circle CircleShape : circleList) {
            CircleShape.collision();
            CircleShape.drawCircle(g);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(new Main());
    }

}
```

Circle Class

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Circle extends Shape {

    public Circle(int x, int y) {
        super(x, y); 
        super.setSize(200, 200);
    }

    public void drawCircle(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(colour);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 200, 200);
    }

    public void collision() {   
        for (Circle CircleShape : Main.circleList) {
            System.out.println(CircleShape);
            System.out.println(CircleShape.getxPos());

            if (this.intersects(CircleShape)) {
                System.out.println("collision detected");
             } else {
                System.out.println("no collision detected");
            }

         }  
    }

}
```

Shape Class

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Shape extends Rectangle {

    //int x, y;
    Color colour;

    public Shape(int x, int y) {
        //this.setxPos(x);
        //this.setyPos(y);
        this.setPos(x, y);
    }
/*
    public int getxPos() {
        return this.x;
    }

    public void setxPos(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getyPos() {
        return this.y;
    }

    public void setyPos(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
*/

    public void setPos(int x, int y) {
        super.setLocation(x, y);
    }

    public Point getPos() {
        return new Point(x, y);
    }

}
```

Comment: You should call `super.setLocation(x, y)` in `setxPos` and `setyPos` methods, otherwise the coordinates will be ignored. Redefining variables in a child class does not override variables in the superclass.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have created a new getter and setter method using the `super.setLocation(x, y)`, however, the collision detection is still not working.

Comment: Can you please update the question with the new code?

Comment: Done. See edits above.

Comment: Well, you also need to use `setSize`. You fill a 200x200 oval in the `drawCircle` method, but the class does not have this information. put `super.setSize(200, 200)` in the `Circle` constructor. If it still doesn't work you need to debug and check all the values from the class.

Comment: Perfect. Everything is working now. I have edited the above code to provide a working solution. Since you have not posted an answer could you please do so, so I can accept it.

Comment: Posted it. Have a look at it, I edited the way you specify x, y, width and height to make things more simple too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `intersects` method expect x, y, width and height properties to be correctly set, because they are used to detect if an object collides with another.

So, in your setter methods you need to invoke `super.setLocation(newX, newY)`, and you should provide a valid width and height too.

So, it should be:

```
public void setxPos(int x) {
    this.x = x;
    super.setLocation(x, y);
}

public void setyPos(int y) {
    this.y = y;
    super.setLocation(x, y);
}
```

and

```
public Circle(int x, int y) {
    super(x, y); 
    super.setSize(200, 200);
}
```

Or, you could just use the already provided methods from class `Rectangle`:

```
public Circle(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    super(x, y, width, height);
}
```

And also use `setLocation` instead of `setxPos` and `setyPos`.

The complete code would become like this:

`Shape` class

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Shape extends Rectangle {

    Color colour;

    public Shape(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        // provided by the Rectangle class. Needed for proper collision detection
        super(x, y, width, height);
    }
}
```

`Circle` class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Circle extends Shape {

    public Circle(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        super(x, y, width, height);
    }

    public void drawCircle(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(super.colour);
        // instead of writing values here, we get them from width and height fields
        g.fillOval(x, y, (int) getWidth(), (int) getHeight());
    }

    public void collision() {
        for (Circle CircleShape : Main.circleList) {
            System.out.println(CircleShape);
            System.out.println(CircleShape.getLocation().x);

            if (this.intersects(CircleShape)) {
                System.out.println("collision detected");
            } else {
                System.out.println("no collision detected");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

`Main` class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main extends JPanel {

    public static List<Circle> circleList = new ArrayList<>();
    private static Random random = new Random();

    public Main() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            // width and height are specified here instead of inside the Circle.drawCircle method.
            circleList.add(new Circle(random.nextInt(500), random.nextInt(500), 200, 200));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (Circle CircleShape : circleList) {
            CircleShape.collision();
            CircleShape.drawCircle(g);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(new Main());
    }

}
```